# R: Group by value for barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data.frame similar to this one

```
dat <- data.frame(
    elevation =sample(0:300, 500, replace=TRUE),
    classes = sample(1:3, 50, replace=TRUE))

> head(dat)
  elevation classes
1       116       1
2         8       1
3        57       2
4       130       3
5        62       1
6        15       1
```

I am trying to group the data by range in 50m increments and then count up all the values of the same class. I am trying to create a hypsography barplot like the following one in the image below.

[image]

What I have managed is to group my data into ranges, but how could I count up all the items for each range and differentiate between the classes so that I can plot it the same way as in the example above? The class numbers represent different landuse types.

```
library("data.table")
library("dplyr")

dat$range <- cut(dat$elevation, breaks = seq(0,300,50), include.lowest = T)

head(dat)
  elevation classes     range
1       116       1 (100,150]
2         8       1    [0,50]
3        57       2  (50,100]
4       130       3 (100,150]
5        62       1  (50,100]
6        15       1    [0,50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
require(ggplot2);
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(y = elevation, x = range))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(
    aes(fill = as.factor(classes)),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE));
gg <- gg + coord_flip();
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  elevation classes     range
1       116       1 (100,150]
2         8       1    [0,50]
3        57       2  (50,100]
4       130       3 (100,150]
5        62       1  (50,100]
6        15       1    [0,50]", header = T, row.names = 1)
```